# Running a single testsuite by default in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

My PHPUnit configuration file has two test suites, `unit` and `system`. When I run the test runner `vendor/bin/phpunit`, it runs all tests in both suites. I can target a single suite with the `testsuite` flag: `vendor/bin/phpunit --testsuite unit`, but I need to configure the test runner to run only the `unit` suite by default, and to run `integration` only when specifically called with the testsuite flag.

My configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="unit">
      <directory>tests/Unit</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="integration">
      <directory>tests/Integration</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
  <filter>
    <whitelist>
      <directory suffix=".php">src</directory>
    </whitelist>
  </filter>
  <logging>
    <log type="coverage-clover" target="build/clover.xml"/>
  </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Isn't better to create both `phpunit_unit.sh` and `phpunit_integration.sh` file, with the configurations inside?

Comment: Was an answer to the converse ever found? A way to run some tests NOT by default - for example massive-long-running ones that test upgrade scripts? So which must be included.

Comment: I might have an answer to this later about an "alternate" way that I generally prefer... the answer (even the accepted one) is quite involved. think it matters? Or not worth the typing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to list multiple testsuites from a phpunit.xml file, but then only run one. However, if you do have some control over a fuller integration and testing environment where you can configure things more exactly, you can have more than one phpunit configuration files, and set one (or more) with more involved environments to set the command-line parameter `--configuration <file>` option with a configuration that will do more. This at least makes sure that the simplest config will run in the easiest fashion.

The two files can be called whatever you like if you run them specifically, but it may be worth thinking about having the quick-to-run file called the default `phpunit.xml`, and the specifically named and extended filem as `phpunit.xml.dist`. **The .dist file will be automatically run by default if the original plain `.xml` does not exist**. Another option is to have the `phpunit.xml.dist` file in a code repository, but then copy it to a `phpunit.xml` file, with less testsuite's, which is not in itself checked into version control, and is only kept locally (it would probably also be marked as ignored in a .gitignore file, or similar).

Comment: PHPUnit (since 6.1.0) now does support defining a default testsuite, so this workaround is no longer needed.

Comment: @GaryJ: A link (at least) to where this is from would by really hypertext friendly. But thanks a lot for the comment and the version number :) /E: Ooops, just seeing you have it in your [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45446071/367456)

Answer (score 29):

Since [PHPUnit 6.1.0](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/ChangeLog-6.1.md#610---2017-04-07), there is now support for a `defaultTestSuite` attribute.

Take a look at https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/pull/2533

This can be used amongst the other `phpunit` attributes like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/6.2/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         defaultTestSuite="unit"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="integration">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">tests/Integration</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

You can now run `phpunit` instead of `phpunit --testsuite unit`.

The name of the testsuite may well be case-sensitive, so watch out for that.

Comment: At the time of writing (July 2019) - this will take a long time to filter down to most users and it'd be better just to use groups and a README at minimum or have something else run the tests (and detect if it's not used, saying "run [thing to copy and paste]" instead) 
Although I don't know how large of the user-base are on it the most recent of 3 "popular" things I checked was 3.7.something (28?) - obviously internal users will know there targets. But yeah if possible don't use this for a while