# Excluding certain tests from loading in phpunit

Tags: phpunit

Some of my testcases use a custom testing library. Also these testcases are very slow. So I would like to run them only in the build server and not in my local. I want to run the other tests locally.

Following is the directory structure. The ones inside the `slow` directory are the slow test cases that should be excluded.

```
/tests/unit-tests/test-1.php
/tests/unit-tests/test-2.php
/tests/unit-tests/slow/test-1.php
/tests/unit-tests/slow/test-2.php
/tests/unit-tests/foo/test-1.php
/tests/unit-tests/bar/test-2.php
```

I tried creating groups using `@group` annotation. This works, but the issue is that these test files are getting loaded (tests not executed though). Since they require the test library which is not installed locally, it is giving an error.

What is the best way to create the phpunit.xml configuration such that these slow tests are excluded (and not even loaded) by default and can be executed if needed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. In your `phpunit.xml` create 2 test suits - one for CI server and one for local development

```xml
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="all_tests">
        <directory>tests/unit-tests/*</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="only_fast_tests">
        <directory>tests/unit-tests/*</directory>
        <!-- Exclude slow tests -->
        <exclude>tests/unit-tests/slow</exclude>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

So on CI server you can run

```
phpunit --testsuite all_tests
```

And locally

```
phpunit --testsuite only_fast_tests
```

Obviously, you can name test suites as you want.

2. I think preferable way is:

- Create `phpunit.xml.dist` and configure default execution of phpunit (for CI server and all those who just cloned repository)
- Modify `phpunit.xml` by configuring your local execution of phpunit
  (by adding `<exclude>tests/unit-tests/slow</exclude>` to default
  testsuite)
- Exclude `phpunit.xml` from version control.

From the [docs](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html):

> If phpunit.xml or phpunit.xml.dist (**in that order**) exist in the
> current working directory and --configuration is not used, the
> configuration will be automatically read from that file.

---

Some links:

[The XML Configuration File. Test Suites](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.testsuites)

[How to run a specific phpunit xml testsuite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671685/how-to-run-a-specific-phpunit-xml-testsuite)