# How to ignore certain methods in Controller when testing in PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to run a test in a Controller using PHPUnit. I have 4 methods in that controller (setFormProperties, indexAction, confirmAction, completeAction). Now, I want to test setFormProperties and indexAction only. What do I do to ignore confirmAction and  completeAction because whenever i run the test,  they are included when infact they are not included in the test automation in my test scripts. This makes my coverage lines low.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excluding certain tests from loading in phpunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588029/excluding-certain-tests-from-loading-in-phpunit)

Comment: Apparently, no. this deals with excluding files from others. what i wanted was how can i exclude certain methods from a src file when executing a test. :)