# Scrutinizer: how exclude phpunit (or a not commited file containing api keys?)

Tags: php, phpunit, scrutinizer

In my phpunit test I `require_once` an `api_key.php` that of course I have in my .gitignore (it contains my own api keys).

```
<?php
namespace Domoticzapi;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

require_once('api_key.php');

class ClientTest extends TestCase {
}
```

Scrutinizer complains with

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(api_key.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/scrutinizer/build/tests/Domoticzapi/ClientTest.php on line 6
```

How can I exclude this check? Or is there a best approach (other than environment variables that I don't want use)?

Comment: If you changed to an `include_once` it won't fail. (or won't fail because of the `require` if you still need something from there it will fail later)

Comment: I will try... Thank you, for the moment I did esclude entire /test folder

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have api keys required in your test cases?

Comment: Test the code, without doing real calls, use fixtures, so you shouldn't need keys.

Comment: @Devon cause the api I'm consuming sometime are broken/changed. So test unit also to test if values are right. Another path in my mind. Is possible to serve to Scrutinizer different ClassTest ? Cannot find a clear docs.@LawrenceCherone

Comment: The right path is write another test unit. But Scrutinizer want perform the test that I don't want. I did open a more precise question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937828/scrutinizer-and-specific-test-from-phpunit

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you need to set your test command on scrutinizer-ci config file to run just the suite test you need, or provide new phpunit config without the suite that contain those test that need `api_key.php`

refer to this: 
[How to run a specific phpunit xml testsuite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671685/how-to-run-a-specific-phpunit-xml-testsuite)
https://scrutinizer-ci.com/docs/build/running_tests_in_parallel

Comment: I did create another question, more precise, following your path. Cannot get my goal. Please, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50937828/scrutinizer-and-specific-test-from-phpunit