# Scrutinizer and specific test from phpunit

Tags: php, phpunit, scrutinizer

I have this phpunit.xml file:

```
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="domoticz-api">
      <directory suffix="Test.php">tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="scrutinizer">
        <file>tests/Domoticzapi4Scrutinizer/ClientTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Following this answer: [How to run a specific phpunit xml testsuite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671685/how-to-run-a-specific-phpunit-xml-testsuite)  In my server I can do:

`./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --testsuite scrutinizer`

to perform test. Other test (main test) for several reason I want to exclude from scrutinizer.

So, in config file of scrutinizer I have:

```
build:
    nodes:
        analysis:
            project_setup:
                override:
                    - 'true'
            tests:
                override:
                    - php-scrutinizer-run
                    - command: 'php ./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --testsuite scrutinizer'

        tests: true

coding_style:
    php:
        indentation:
            general:
                use_tabs: true
```

But unfortunately Scrutinizer try and want execute first group of test (domoticz-api) that fails.

I did try also without the single quote, configuration is validated but Scrutinizer perform first group.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the anser for some one...

After some try and error, I got the solution:

```
build:
    nodes:
        analysis:
            project_setup:
                override:
                    - 'true'
            tests:
                override:
                    - php ./vendor/bin/phpunit --configuration phpunit.xml --testsuite scrutinizer

coding_style:
    php:
        indentation:
            general:
                use_tabs: true
```

One simply command in override and remove the "test: true". Don't know if also removing the quote impacts.